# Audio player with time tags

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm running a small podcast for my school. I've used a simple flash player so far, but according to the visitors, that would be great if there were clackable time tags for the each topics.

So, for example if somebody is interested in a topic, but that is in the end of the podcast and he doesn't want to listen the whole stuff for variable reasons, he could just click on that topic's time tag and the player would jump to the certain point.

Has anybody got some ideas to make this?

(no PHP, please, if it's possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<audio id="player" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/hanselminutes/hanselminutes_0363.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume+=0.1">Volume Up</button>
    <button onclick="var mediaElement = document.getElementById('player');
mediaElement.currentTime = 122;
">
        Next Time</button>
</div>
```

first click play and next click on Next Time,i check it's work
see this link and my code.it's working
http://jsfiddle.net/ashi2009/Xtf4N/

Comment: Awesome! :) Thanks! Is it possible to put that timeline-thing (i dont know, what's that's name?) ?

Comment: with css yes u can,but i don't know how exactly